# Unable to Place Order with Authorize .net Payment from Admin backend

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have configured Authorized .net in Magento 2 site. For this, I am using Sandbox credentials. From Frontend I am able to place order with Authorize.net. But from backend admin, I observed below (scenarios):

**Case 1: with Valid authorize (test) credentials** : - we are able to place order.

**Case 2: with inValid credentials (expiry date):** - the popup alert comes on clicking on Submit Order button with message:- "Gateway Error: The credit card has expired.". Later if we provided valid credentials then its giving Duplicate Key error - "Order saving error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '000000045-1' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID' ".

That means still there is issue with Authorize net/Magento 2.

Please let me know how we can overcome/fix this.

Note: I am using - Magento EE version 2.0.7.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? Please answer your question